# geom_bar + coord_polar labels with lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to label the series of concentric circles below with the labels from `C` in the data frame

I am aware that I could use something like `geom_text_repel` but I cannot seem to get it to work.

In addition, I cannot seem to get rid of the tick marks on the upper left.

[image]

```
df <- data.frame(C=c(rep("The macro-environment",4),rep("The industry",4),rep("Competitors",4),rep("The organisation",4)))

ggplot(df, aes(factor(1), fill = C)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, colour = NA, show.legend = FALSE, alpha = .8) +    
  coord_polar() +
    labs(
        x = "",
        y = ""
    ) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#289045", "#beddc7", "#d4dfe9", "#286291")) +
    theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
    theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A second option would be to add your labels as curved labels using the `geomtextpath` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(df, aes(factor(1), fill = C)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, colour = NA, show.legend = FALSE, alpha = .8) +
  geom_textpath(aes(x = .5, label = C, group = C),
    stat = "count", position = position_stack(vjust = .5),
    vjust = 1
  ) +
  coord_polar() +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = ""
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#289045", "#beddc7", "#d4dfe9", "#286291")) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(factor(1), fill = C)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, colour = NA, show.legend = FALSE, alpha = .8) + 
  geom_text(stat = 'count', aes(label = C), size = 6,
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            vjust = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2)) +
  coord_polar(start = pi) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#289045", "#beddc7", "#d4dfe9", "#286291")) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Would have expected the `geomtextpath` option from you. (;

Comment: @stefan lol. I actually had that as an answer initially,  but didn't like the way the central label looked.

Comment: Yeah. The central one doesn't look nice. But for the other ones goemtextpath works really nice

Comment: I got around the central one by adjusting the size of the middle circle to be slightly bigger than the rest, and the second most inner circle to be in-between the biggest and smaller outer ones, while adjusting the text sizes down slightly!